# How does Oracle en-Vec work in multiplayer games?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-multiplayer

When playing in 2v2 or 3v3, if I activate [Oracle en-Vec](https://scryfall.com/card/tmp/31/oracle-en-vec) ability, can other opponents' creatures attack?

I hope no because it says:

> other creatures can’t attack

And it doesn't say it's only other creatures of target player...

Comment: When you say 2v2, are you referring to the Two-Headed Giant format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, the Oracle's ability prevents other opponents' creatures from attacking on the same turn.**

When the card says "other creatures" without any additional qualifiers, it is referring to every other creature on the battlefield. So, if the targeted opponent takes their turn at the same time as another player, none of that player's creatures can attack.

Comment: Great, useful ;)